# finding the first instance of an integer in command line

Tags: java

how would I find the first int of a command prompt input
say the user inputs

```
jdshusaduidsuiuhd3j
```

what would I use to extract that 3?
I was thinking

```
int whatever = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\D+").nextInt();
```

but it doesn't seem to work so what would I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = in.next();
int whatever = new Scanner(str).useDelimiter("\\D+").nextInt();
```

Comment: do I just add another line of 
int whatever1 = new Scanner(str).useDelimiter("\\D+").nextInt();

if there is more then 1 int in the input like

kffhsjhsfjhf3jifjiefwiijf4nnsjs2jsbfbsi

Comment: Sure, but 'str' must be the substring after the first int.

Comment: If you wanted to get all the integers from a string, just use `str = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");`. Then str will be "342".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.findInLine("\\d+");
    System.out.println(s);
```